# Could user names in comments be updated when a user changes their name?

Tags: feature-request, comments

I changed my name a couple years ago on the stackexchange family of sites.  It was an overall good experience.

I would share links to my answers to my facebook friends and coworkers, but I don't.  This is because they might see a comment @'ing me and that would reveal my previous name to people that don't know it.

I know I'm not the only person to have this issue and it would be nice if there was some way to change the comment text - either changing or removing the @'ing.

Edit: When an account is closed, the user name changes to a generic one: user35135 - When this happens, @'ing in comments are automatically edited with the generic name.  It seems to me that the code to do the rename in comments already exists.

Comment: It might be better to ask this on meta.stackexchange.com, since this would most likely be a feature affecting every site on the network.  Beyond that, I don't know if mods have the ability to edit comments like that to begin with.

Comment: This was asked about [very early on, on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53419/345161) and has been brought up a few times since then. I think I brought it up a few years ago at some point. Generally people like the idea but don't think it's practical.

Comment: @MBraedley - Mods *can* edit comments, but it's a manual process. It would be impractical to expect Mods to manually edit every comment that mentions someone when they change their name.

Comment: Having said that, if there's a specific thread or set of comments that you want updated @Amy - I think we could accommodate it as a special request. (Of course, if the comments aren't even relevant any more we could just purge the thread in its entirety)

Comment: Thanks for the offer.  Here are comments with my old name on any answer to a question where I have an answer with 10 rep or more:
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/107775/9192
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/77215/9192
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/38744/9192
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/108460/9192
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/108898/9192
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/86331/9192

While going through these, I found an answer which used my old name and I was able to edit it (yay!) https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/78695/9192

Comment: @AmyB - Done! I hope I didn't miss any :)

Comment: Thanks!  I really appreciate this.